# pygame screen not refreshing

Tags: python, pygame

So i am new to python, and im working on a code that draws a spirograph and moves it. When I ran the code, all I got was a black screen with no circles on it. Im sure that im drawing circles and the screen is refreshing because i printed out its coordinates. However, the screen is still black. Any help?

```
import pygame
import math
import sys
import time
#setting colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255,  0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
ORANGE = (255, 127, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
PURPLE = (160, 32, 240)
#setting what order the colors go in
listCircleColor = (RED, BLUE, GREEN, ORANGE, YELLOW, PURPLE, WHITE)
#how many circles per color
intGroup = 5
#the space between each circle
turnangle = 360/35
#width of screen
width = 600
#height of screen
height = 600
#radius of circles
radius = 100
#making the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
#if the code is running, then continue
running = True
##.draw.circle(screen, BLUE, (0, 0), radius, width=2)
circles = []

#draw
alpha = turnangle
for i in range(intGroup):
    for cl in listCircleColor:
        surfacetemp = pygame.Surface((width, height))

        ##circlerect = pygame.rect
        if alpha > 0 and alpha < 90:
            circlerect = pygame.draw.circle(surfacetemp, cl, (300 + radius * 
math.cos(math.radians(alpha)), 300 + radius * math.sin(math.radians(alpha))), radius, width=2)
            # second quarter of circles
        if alpha > 90 and alpha < 180:
            circlerect = pygame.draw.circle(surfacetemp, cl, (300 - radius * 
math.cos(math.radians(180 - alpha)), 300 + radius * math.sin(math.radians(180 - alpha))), radius, width=2)
            # third quarter of circles
        if alpha > 180 and alpha < 270:
            circlerect = pygame.draw.circle(surfacetemp, cl, (300 - radius * 
math.cos(math.radians(270 - alpha)), 300 - radius * math.sin(math.radians(270 - alpha))), radius, width=2)
            # last quarter of circles
        if alpha > 270 and alpha < 360:
            circlerect = pygame.draw.circle(surfacetemp, cl, (300 + radius * 
math.cos(math.radians(360 - alpha)), 300 - radius * math.sin(math.radians(360 - alpha))), radius, width=2)

        alpha = alpha + turnangle
        ##circles.append(circlerect)
        circles.append(surfacetemp)

#move"

#exit only when user clicks on exit button
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    for crect in circles:
        ret = crect.get_rect()
        ret.right += 5
        ret.left += 5

        screen.blit(screen, ret)




    ##screen.blit(crect,crect)
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(20)
    pygame.display.update()

    ##for center, color in circles:
    ##    pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, center, radius, 2)
        ##pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: did you mean to use `screen.blit(crect, ret)`? otherwise you are blitting the `screen` to itself

Comment: Yes, I did mean to use screen.blit. I always knew i was doing something wrong with the screen.blit, but i didnt know what it was. How do I make it blit to the correct screen?

Comment: you blit to correct `screen` but you blit wrong objects - you have to use `crect` instead of `screen` as first argument `screen.blit(crect, ret)` - but you have `screen.blit(screen, ret)`

Comment: you have list with `circles` (surfaces) but you don't have list with `positions` (ie. `Rect`) for these `circles` - so it will always draw them in the same positions. `Surfaces` can't keep positions.

Comment: surfaces use colors `R,G,B` and they have black background - so you can see only once circle because other circles are hidden by other surfaces with black backgrounds. You would have to convert surfaces to 32bit to have `R, G, B, transparency/alpha` and make them transparent.

Comment: Thanks! For the lists, what am I supposed to do? Am I supposed to make a list of coordinates? Im a bit confused. Also, I searched around for awhile, but I couldnt find how to convert a surface to 32bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You blit on correct `screen` but you blit wrong objects.

You should use `crect` instead of `screen` as first argument

```
screen.blit(crect, ret)
```

but you have

```
screen.blit(screen, ret)
```

so you blit `black screen` on `black screen`

---

`Surface` as default uses 24bit colors `R,G,B` and it has black background so your code shows only one circle because other circles are behind black backgrounds of other surfaces.

To make transparent background you have to convert surfaces to 32bit colors `R,G,B,Alpha`

```
surfacetemp = surfacetemp.convert_alpha()
```

and fill background with `transparent` color - last value (`alpha`) has to be `0`, other values don't matter (if you don't need semi-transparent color)

```
surfacetemp.fill((0,0,0,0))
```

And now you can see all circles.

---

There is also other problem.

`Surface` can keep image but not position. `surface.get_rect()` gives always only `(0, 0, width, height)`. If you want to animate then you need another list to keep positions - you can use `pygame.Rect()` for this.

At start I create `circles_rect` with all `get_rect()` and later I use this list to change position and blit it.

Animation need also to clear screen in every loop to remove circles in old positions. I use `screen.fill((0,0,0))` to draw black background.

---

If you change `rec.right += 5` then you don't have to change `rec.left` because it is changed automatically (the same with  `rec.centerx`)

Running

```
rec.right += 5
rec.left += 5
```

gives the same result as

```
rec.right += 10
```

---

**EDIT:**

You don't have to make different calculations for different quarters.

```
import pygame
import math

# setting colors
WHITE  = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE   = (  0,   0, 255)
GREEN  = (  0, 255,   0)
RED    = (255,   0,   0)
ORANGE = (255, 127,   0)
YELLOW = (255, 255,   0)
PURPLE = (160,  32, 240)

# setting what order the colors go in
listCircleColor = (RED, BLUE, GREEN, ORANGE, YELLOW, PURPLE, WHITE)

# how many circles per color
intGroup = 5

# the space between each circle
turnangle = 360/35

# width of screen
width = 600

# height of screen
height = 600

# radius of circles
radius = 100

# making the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

# .draw.circle(screen, BLUE, (0, 0), radius, width=2)
circles = []
circles_rect = []

# draw

alpha = turnangle

for i in range(intGroup):
    for cl in listCircleColor:
        surfacetemp = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        surfacetemp = surfacetemp.convert_alpha()
        surfacetemp.fill((0,0,0,0))

        x = 300 + radius * math.cos(math.radians(alpha))
        y = 300 + radius * math.sin(math.radians(alpha))

        circlerect = pygame.draw.circle(surfacetemp, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)

        alpha = alpha + turnangle
        circles.append(surfacetemp)
        circles_rect.append(surfacetemp.get_rect())
        
# move

# exit only when user clicks on exit button

# if the code is running, then continue
running = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
            #running = False
            
    screen.fill((0,0,0))  # remove previous circles
            
    for crect, ret in zip(circles, circles_rect):
        ret.right += 5
        #ret.left += 5
        screen.blit(crect, ret)

    result = clock.tick(25)
    fps = clock.get_fps()

    text = f'FRAME TIME: {result:.02f} ms | FPS: {fps:.02f}'
    pygame.display.set_caption(text)
    #print(text)
    
    #pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Its much more clearer now. I have one last question: what does for crect, ret in zip(circles, circles_rect): mean?

Comment: `zip()` gets two lists and create pairs `(circle1, rect1)`, `(circle2, rect2)`, etc. So I can work with `circle` and its `rectangle`.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: BTW: I keep some answers on GitHub [python-examples](https://github.com/furas/python-examples) and there is example with [pygame transparency](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/transparency/complex-example)